# JSON image value in NetworkImage Widget

Tags: flutter, dart

in this code I cannot see the article?.imageUrl value in NetworkImage. I am getting this error:

The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

any help?

in listTile as Text I can see the value (link) of image but in NetworkImage cannot.

```
Widget build(context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xffeeeeee),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          'List User Example',
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(
          10.0,
        ),
        child: FutureBuilder<Article>(
          future: _futureArticle,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Article> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final article = snapshot.data?.data;
              return Container(
                height: 500.0,
                width: 500.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      image: NetworkImage(article?.imageUrl), fit: BoxFit.cover),
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                ),
                child: Card(
                  elevation: 4.0,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      'Title: ${article?.title}',
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      'Content: ${article?.imageUrl}',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text(
                '${snapshot.error}',
              );
            } else {
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The error is because under nullsafety NetworkImage() can't take a null argument, and `article?.imageUrl` can evaluate to null. You could do something like `NetworkImage(article == null ? 'https:/my.com/default.png' : article!.imageUrl)`

Comment: still same problem

Comment: Sorry - also put a ! after imageUrl: `NetworkImage(article == null ? 'https:/my.com/default.png' : article!.imageUrl!)`  FWIW I think what I'm suggesting here with bang operators is sort of frowned on, since without upstream checks you can still have null errors which defeats the whole nullsafety feature. The idea of nullsafety is that somewhere a value should be null-checked before it is used, and if a function doesn't take a nullable type (i.e with a ? suffix like 'String?') then it doesn't check and expects the caller to have checked for null values.

Comment: thanks now works.